# Acionar submit dentro do iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

É possível acionar um submit via iframe?

Estou abrindo a página **formulario.php** via iframe com modal. Ela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O botão verde, é o submit que vem da página formulario.php.
- O botão azul e cinza vem junto com o modal (código abaixo).

Esse exemplo o form é pequeno, mas quando o formulário e grande, o botão verde se perde, **e a forma que o modal apresenta é bem intuitivo**.

Código modal:

```
<div id="modal-form" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item iframe" src="formulario.php" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>Cancelar</button>
        <button id="salvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i>Salvar</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloca `target="_parent"` no `<form>`.

Comment: @Sam e como faço para o botão salvar que esta no modal enviar o comando submit para dentro do iframe?

Comment: Não testei mas acho que é isso: `$("iframe").contents().find("form").submit();`

Comment: @Sam, testei, mas não funcionou.

Comment: @Sam, tem outra sugestão?

Comment: Creio que você pode criar um `trigger('my-event');` com seu Jquery.
Dai você pode dispara o seu evento de um outro contexto , como você ta usando Iframe creio que uma trigger possa ajudar.

Comment: @RicardoLucas eu não sei como devo montar esse `trigger`, você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @Sam funcionou. Eu não havia colocado como função. Como fez no codigo e mudei aqui. Registra aqui para eu marcar como concluido. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se você encontrou a resposta correta se você puder postar ajuda...
Alguém pode ter a mesa dúvida e isso vai ajudar essa pessoa também :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode acessar os elementos dentro de um iframe usando:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("seletor");
```

Onde `"seletor"` pode ser um id, class, tag etc., ou seja, um seletor normal jQuery.

No caso de submeter o formulário dentro do iframe, basta buscar pela tag `form` e usar o método `.submit()`:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("form").submit();
```

E para abrir a página especificada no `action` do formulário do iframe na janela principal, coloque na tag `form` o atributo `target="_parent"`. Exemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="pagina.php" target="_parent">
```

Comment: Sam, uma pergunta, como fazer para que antes de executar o submit verifique se o form esta preenchido. Digo isso porque o os forms tem o `required`, mas o submit esta ignorando e enviado mesmo sem o preenchimento.

Comment: no campo do cpf eu tambem tenho um validador ao final do digito ele verifica se existe, caso exista ele bloqueia o submit.

Comment: Mas tem um botão "submit" no formulário dentro do iframe?

Comment: Em vez de fazer como na resposta, poderia mandar um click no botão que irá validar o required: `$("iframe").contents().find("form button").click();`

Comment: Fantástico, funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Para iniciar dentro do contexto da seu modal você vai criar uma referencia .

```
$('#modal-form')[0].contentWindow.$('body').trigger('text-event');
```

Dai você deve dispara de um novo contexto o evento.

```
$('#algumBotao').on('text-event', function(e) {
  alert("Modal deve fechar");
});
```

Tenta assim pode da certo ...